# How to keep url parameter Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, parameters, pagination, search-engine

I create my own searching at my website and I have create page search result page which contains `<php>` code, I use plugin PHP-Exec at my search result page. I create pagination, but it seems not work properly.
When I click "Next" for next result of my own searching the url parameter is redirect to wrong url.

The Url should be :

```
http://inindonesia.org/hasil-pencarian?phrase=sofa+bed&page=1
```

But, it redirect to :

```
http://inindonesia.org/hasil-pencarian/1?phrase=sofa bed
```

It is wrong URL exactly, and I feel stuck because automatically it can affect the search results of my own search :( . For information, I use Wordpress Multisite, any ideas for keeping my URL parameter?

Here my code :

```
<?php
$dbhost = 'myhost';
$dbuser = 'mydbuser';
$dbpass = 'mydbpass';
$hasil = $_GET[phrase];
$type = str_replace(' ','+',$hasil);
$rec_limit = 2;

$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
if(! $conn ){
  die('Database tidak terkoneksi' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db('mydb');
    $sql = "SELECT count(wp_mp_term_relationships.post_id) FROM `wp_mp_term_relationships` INNER JOIN wp_mp_products ON wp_mp_products.id = wp_mp_term_relationships.post_id INNER JOIN wp_mp_terms ON wp_mp_terms.term_id = wp_mp_term_relationships.term_id WHERE wp_mp_terms.name = '$hasil'";   
    $retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );

if(! $retval ){
  die('Tidak dapat Menerima Data: ' . mysql_error());
}

    $row = mysql_fetch_array($retval, MYSQL_NUM );
    $rec_count = $row[0];

if( isset($_GET{'page'} ) ){
   $page = $_GET{'page'} + 1;
   $offset = $rec_limit * $page ;
}else{
   $page = 0;
   $offset = 0;
}

$left_rec = $rec_count - ($page * $rec_limit);
$query = "SELECT * FROM `wp_mp_term_relationships` INNER JOIN wp_mp_products ON wp_mp_products.id = wp_mp_term_relationships.post_id INNER JOIN wp_mp_terms ON wp_mp_terms.term_id = wp_mp_term_relationships.term_id WHERE wp_mp_terms.name = '$hasil' LIMIT $offset, $rec_limit";
$query_retval = mysql_query( $query, $conn );

if(! $query_retval ){
  die('Tidak dapat menerima data ' . mysql_error());
}

while($result = mysql_fetch_array($query_retval, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    echo "<h3><a href=" . $result[post_permalink] . " target=_blank>" . $result[post_title] . "</a></h3>";
    $content = $result[post_content];
    $content_len = strlen($content);
    if ( $content_len > 150 ){
        echo "<div style='margin-left: 26px; margin-top: 6px; margin-bottom: -26px;'><h3 style='font-size: 13px; line-height: -0.5'>" . substr($content, 0, 150) . " ...<a href=" . $result[post_permalink] . " target=_blank> (more)</a></h3></div>";
    }else{
        echo "<div style='margin-left: 26px; margin-top: 6px; margin-bottom: -26px;'><h3 style='font-size: 13px; line-height: -0.5'>" . $content . "</h3></div>";
    }
    echo "<hr>"; 
 }

if( $page > 0 ){
   $last = $page - 1;
   echo "<a href=\"$_PHP_SELF?phrase=$type&page=$last\">Last 5 Records</a> |";
   echo "<a href=\"$_PHP_SELF?phrase=$type&page=$page\">Next 5 Records</a>";
}else if( $page == 0 ){
   echo "<p>" . $_PHP_SELF . "?phrase=" . $type . "&page=" . $page . "</p>";
   echo "<a href=\"$_PHP_SELF?phrase=$type&page=$page\">Next 5 Records</a>";
}else if( $left_rec < $rec_limit ){
   $last = $page - 1;
   echo "<a href=\"$_PHP_SELF?phrase=$&page=$last\">Last 5 Records</a>";
}

mysql_close($conn);
?>
```

Comment: Where's the code to control this?.... we're not magicians here, jimmy!

Comment: @Ohgodwhy yes, sorry I am forget attach my code :)

Answer (score 2):

Don't use key "page" for pagination. Instead use other keys to identify your page number because it is your custom coding for search.

When you pass page in query string, wordpress will detect as page parameter and redirect to default URL structure for paging (`http://inindonesia.org/hasil-pencarian/1`)

When you change key for your pagination, wordpress will not recognize paging and won't change your URL.

Comment: you can try key "pg" instead of page

Comment: @Unihedron which 'page' key should I change ? FYI, I have edit my question and attach my code, Thanks :)